# GCP Endpoint's using multiple authentication

Tags: authentication, firebase-authentication, swagger, google-cloud-endpoints

I have the following security schemes defined for a method in my swagger file:

```yaml
...
    get:
      ...
      security:
      - api_key: []
      - firebase: []
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    in: query
    name: key
    type: apiKey
  firebase:
    authorizationUrl: ''
    flow: implicit
    type: oauth2
    x-google-audiences: project-id
    x-google-issuer: https://securetoken.google.com/project-id
    x-google-jwks_uri: https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com
```

However, it will not work if I try to send a request using an api key, but it will if I use a firebase token (even if I do not provide the api key).

The response:

```
{
    "code": 16,
    "message": "JWT validation failed: Missing or invalid credentials",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
            "stackEntries": [],
            "detail": "auth"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I remove firebase from the security definition, then it will work using the api key.

Is it a known issue that an api key security scheme will not work if there is also an oauth2 for the same method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that "OR" security requirements [are not supported](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations#security_requirements_containing_an_api_key) when one of the alternatives is an API key. Therefore, you are experiencing the right behavior.

If you provide both alternatives the API key will be ignored, but if OAuth2 is removed and it only accepts the API key, it works.

According to the same [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations#security_requirements_containing_an_api_key) that I attached, you could require both authentication methods using an "AND" condition. Something like this:

```
...
security:
- api_key: []
  firebase: []
....
```

Comment: Thank you - I missed that one. That's quite annoying, would you have any workaround for this one on the top of your head?

Comment: @AlWld Currently there's no way to let the client choose one, you have to force either API token-only, OAuth2-only or both. One option that you have is to create two similar endpoints that differ in the authentication method, but that would be a bit overkill and not what you would need. I have found a [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/113936590) requesting this exact feature, you should star it in order to indicate that you are interested in it. Notice that it doesn't have any guarantee of being implemented nor any ETA.

Comment: @AlWld, this is considered working as intended, the [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/113936590) was closed by the Product Team with the explanation that the API key is not considered an authentication provider.